# Find the sum to $n$ terms of the series $10+84+734+....$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation

Find the sum to n terms of the series $10+84+734+....$

1. $\frac{9(9^n+1)}{10} + 1$
2. $\frac{9(9^n-1)}{8} + 1  $
3. $\frac{9(9^n-1)}{8} + n $
4. $ \frac{9(9^n-1)}{8} + n^2$

---

My attempt:

I'm getting option $(4)$.

For $n=1$, all options are right,

For $n=2$, sum must be $10+84=94$.

> Can you explain in formal way? Please.

Comment: What is the common rule that produces the terms 10, 84, 734, ....? It is not at all clear how the series continues.

Comment: It's supposed to be one of the 4 options? Because neither of them is correct, in fact neither of them gives natural numbers

Comment: The formula should be something like $\frac{9(9^n-1)}{8}+n^2$. Maybe a typo in (4)? Btw. what do you mean by “explain in a formal way”?

Comment: For $n=2$ the option (4) is not an integer

Comment: I think there is a typo, none of the four options give 84 as second term (neither 84+10).

Comment: Thanks for point out for typo. May be none or all are correct options. I should focus on correct procedure.

Comment: @Piquito, in general $(x-1)|(x^n-1)$, so $n=2$ most certainly gives (4) to be an integer.

Comment: You are right. I mistook $9^2$ with $9\cdot 2$ (unforgivable!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terms are neither geometric nor arithmetic progression. There could be more than one recurrence relations that can describe the $n^{th}$ term, but it is unlikely that you could deduce it based on $3$ terms only. Since this is only a multiple choice questoon, I suspect that they expect you to find out the right choice using your method.

On the mathematical side, we can find out the general term $T(n)$ by subtracting the sum of first $n-1$ terms from the sum of first $n$ terms. (By the way I suppose the option is $\frac{9(9^n-1)}8+n^2$

$$T(n)=\frac{9^{n+1}-9}8 + n^2  - \frac{9^n-9}8 -(n-1)^2$$

$$T(n)=9^n +2n -1$$

Which is pretty hard to guess based on the first three terms only

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Answer (score 2):

REMARK.-If the first three terms $10+84+734+.....$ are correctly written then the formation law could be $a_n=9^n+2n-1$ However this conflicts with the four given options (in comment I suggested could be a typo).

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

*Note:* I think formal issues are not that essential. But you have to reasonably show that you have checked *all variants* and derive the appropriate conclusion. Here is one variation of the theme.

> We have four options each providing a sequence 
>   \begin{align*}
> (a_n)_{n\geq 1}=(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)
> \end{align*}
>
> The sequence against we have to check is
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(10,10+84,10+84+734,\ldots\right)=\left(10,94,828,\ldots\right)
> \end{align*}

We do so by listing each of the four alternatives as far as necessary:

\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{9(9^n+1)}{10} + 1\right)_{n\geq 1}&=(10,74.1,\ldots)\tag{1}\\
\left(\frac{9(9^n-1)}{8} + 1\right)_{n\geq 1}&=(10,91,\ldots)\tag{2}\\
\left(\frac{9(9^n-1)}{8} + n\right)_{n\geq 1}&=(10,92,\ldots)\tag{3}\\
\left(\frac{9(9^n-1)}{8} + n^2\right)_{n\geq 1}&=(10,94,828,\ldots)\tag{4}\\
\end{align*}

> We observe alternatives (1) to (3) are no proper solution, since the second element of each of these three alternatives is not equal 
>   \begin{align*}
> 10+84=94
> \end{align*}
>   The last option (4) coincides in all three values $(10,10+84,10+84+734)=(10,94,828)$ with the series which is to generate.
>
> and conclude the sequence
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(\frac{9(9^n-1)}{8} + n^2\right)_{n\geq 1}=(10,94,828,\ldots)
> \end{align*}
>   is the solution.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay: You're welcome and thanks, typo corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is option 4.

Let $S(n)=\frac{9(9^n-1)}{8} + n^2$

Then $S(1)=10$, matching with the given series.

$S(2)=94$ which is equal to $10+84$(sum to $2$ terms), matching with the given series.

$S(3)=828=10+84+734$(sum to $3$ terms), again matching with the given series.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is an old question, I'd like to contribute a remark of mine on this, especially, after my long absence from the site. I realized at one glance that the sequence is $$9 + 1, 9^2 + 3, 9^3 + 5, \cdots,$$ which led me to think that the general term of the sequence is $9^n + 2 n + 1$. Summing from $1$ to $n$, we have $$9 (9^n - 1) / 8 + n^2.$$

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay You're welcome, boss!